# Validating Array Value in php

Tags: php

I want to validate the value inside the array which is inserting from the text field. is user has inserted his full name or not. I want confirm all the values contain only text, number and spaces of 20 char length before inserting into databse.

Please suggest any answer.

I have `$g8_sub_vali[] = $_POST["g8_sub$i"];` as a array which has more than 100 fields. I want to check all fields are inserted in format.

Comment: Please, show the array with sample data

Comment: How about you post your code?

Comment: passthrough `array_filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code checks every element of $array to contain only latin characters, numbers and space. The length of the string is between 2 and 20 symbols. Case insensitive:

```
<?php
$array = array(
array(),
"value",
"value 2",
"vagh-% ^",
"texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext",
);

check_elements($array);

function check_elements(&$array)
// {{{
{
    foreach($array as $value)
    {
        if (!is_array($value))
        {
            if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\s]{2,20}$/i', $value))
            {
                print $value." good\n";
            }
            else
            {
                print $value." bad\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            check_elements($value);
        }
    }
}
// }}}
```

Prints:

```
value good
value 2 good
vagh-% ^ bad
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext bad
```

Comment: when I insert your code i got this Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\school\styles\adm\test.php on line 33

Comment: @user2642907 It depends upon your data structure. var_dump the array you are inserting and put the result to your question, so i could correct the answer

Comment: this is the result of var_dump array(16) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> string(6) "adfads" [2]=> string(5) "afkdj" [3]=> string(5) "adfjk" [4]=> string(6) "adfklj" [5]=> string(5) "adfda" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(0) "" [8]=> string(0) "" [9]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(0) "" [13]=> string(0) "" [14]=> string(0) "" [15]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: @user2642907 We can create a recursive function, that will check the nestedarrays. I updated the code. But the action depends upon your requirements for such cases.

Comment: @user2642907 Well, I am expecting you to do some efforts. I gave you the regular expression and the overall design. The rest is in your hands.